# Will the kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation setting in Core Location Improve Location Services for Walking Around?

Tags: iphone, ipad, gps, location, core-location

I have an application that needs to keep very precise data about where a user is walking. Will having kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation turned on as opposed to kCLLocationAccuracyBest gain me anything in this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation is better for what you want to achieve as opposed to kCLLocationAccuracyBest.

the only reason not to pick the BestForNavigation is the support of devices with iOS<4.

As a side note, kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation will also be battery eater...
but not more than 20% in respect to other (from my personal experience).

> As the boys in Apple said:
>
> kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
>   Use the highest possible accuracy and
>   combine it with additional sensor
>   data. This level of accuracy is
>   intended for use in navigation
>   applications that require precise
>   position information at all times and
>   are intended to be used only while the
>   device is plugged in.

Comment: When you say it will 20% of the battery, how long of a time period is this?

Comment: By apple the iPhone 4 provides five hours of navigation (extensive) , thus 20% would be 1 hour assuming the battery is fully charge. please note that this is a very rough estimation...