# SWIFT:Tracking Facebook friends on Google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I am new to IOS/Swift development and I am trying to develop an app which would let me be tracked by my Facebook friends on Google Maps in IOS. I am done with the FB login part and I am even able to get my location on my own screen. I am stuck with the sharing location and tracking part. If anyone has some nice article or code snippet or even brief architecture, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to first create a facebook app and let your user report their location to your FB app and pull their other friends information too.

Regarding of tracking users' location from background, you can refer to this post: [Constantly tracking user location on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624522/constantly-tracking-user-location-on-ios)

Comment: I was talking about something more in terms of like FindMyFriend on a google map. How do I connect the two devices. Should I constantly update the location in an database and then let the friends retrieve it from there. Is there any other way around it?